# How to selectively/conditionally filter Out of Stock products from Magento's advanced search results

Tags: php, magento

I've built a modified search form on top of Magento's advanced search module.

I've found a few tutorials [like this one](http://www.designend.net/en/webmaster-blog,magento-hiding-out-of-stock-products-in-advanced-search-results#comments) showing how to hide/remove Out of Stock products from Magento's advanced search results, but I want to implement a checkbox on the form which allows customers to **choose whether or not** they want to include Out of Stock products in their results.

I'm at the point where I'm determined to find a solution, and I think I may need to add a filter or something to this variable:

```
<?php $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection() ?>
<?php if(!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
```

This code is at the top of the advanced search module's corresponding .phtml layout file (list-as.phtml), and I know it's grabbing the products for the search results.

Am I on the right track, or do I need to focus on the files mentioned in the linked tutorial above? I'm hoping someone has done something like this before within Magento. Thanks for any help/guidance guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd think that something like the following would work (assuming $show_oos is a boolean flag for if a user wants out of stock items shown):

```
if($_productCollection->count() > 0 || $show_oos == true):
```

Comment: That did it, Giga. Had to play around with the code (which is a mess to begin with), but it worked. Thanks!